AWS Amplify Deployed Website Returns HTTP 404 Error - Unable to Display Site
I've recently encountered an issue with my AWS Amplify deployed website. After what seemed like a successful build and deployment process, my website is unexpectedly returning an HTTP 404 error, indicating that the page cannot be found.
Observations & Steps Taken:

The Amplify build process completes without any reported errors.
The deployment process also indicates success.
When trying to access the website, I'm met with an HTTP 404 error message.
I have verified that the build process includes a static 404 page, which is standard.
The logs do not contain any explicit errors related to the 404 issue, except the line for the static 404 page handling (├ ○ /404 1.89 kB 111 kB).
I've checked DNS configurations, and they seem to be in order.

Complications:
I'm at a loss for what could be causing this issue. Could this be related to routing configurations within the application, or perhaps something to do with the domain's DNS settings not properly propagating yet?
Seeking Insights On:

Any potential misconfiguration in the AWS Amplify Console that could lead to this issue.
Possible issues with the deployment process that might not have correctly released or aliased the build to the correct endpoint.
Additional logs or errors that I might have missed which could shine some light on this problem.

Logs Excerpt:
... (previous build and deployment logs)
├ ○ /404 1.89 kB 111 kB
... (subsequent logs)

package.json
{
      "name": "olmo",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "eslint:fix": "npx eslint \"src/**/*.{js,tsx,jsx,ts}\" --fix",
        "lint:filenames": "find src -type f ! -name '*.js' ! -name '*.jsx' ! -name '*.ts' ! -name '*.tsx' ! -name '*.json' ! -name '*.md' ! -name '*.css' -exec echo 'Invalid file extension found:' '{}' ';'",
        "prepare": "husky"
      },
      "husky": {
        "hooks": {
          "pre-commit": "npm run lint:filenames && npm run lint"
        }
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app"
        ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs": "^1.0.27",
        "@next/font": "13.2.4",
        "aws-amplify": "^6.0.27",
        "bing-translate-api": "^4.0.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "formik": "^2.4.5",
        "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
        "openai": "^4.33.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-countup": "^6.4.2",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-select": "^5.8.0",
        "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
        "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "uuid": "^9.0.1",
        "wowjs

": "^1.1.3",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "next": "^14.1.4",
    "prettier-eslint": "^16.3.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^8.0.1"
  }
}

amplify.yml
version: 0.3
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - "**/*"
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*

View:

